# PHP foreach loop adds closing </ul> in IE8

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I have a `foreach` loop like this:

```
<ul>
    <?php

        foreach ($pages['results'] as $row => $value) {
            echo '<li>' . $row . '<ul>';
            foreach ($value as $x => $y) {
                echo '<li><a href="#' . str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($y[2])) . '" title="' . $x . '">' . $x  . '</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</li></ul>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

And, this works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE 9 but not in IE 8.

The CSS is correct, but the last `</ul>` outside the `foreach` closes after the first row of the `foreach`. I hope this makes sense, why is IE 8 doing this?

This is the HTML that is spit out:

### New Home Communities

- Ancaster

  - Ancaster Glen
- Beamsville

  - Discovery
- Binbrook

  - Fairgrounds Finale
  - Parkside Village
- Collingwood

  - Summit Shores
- Hamilton

  - Greenhill Glen
  - Paramount at Valley Park
  - Sherman Oaks
- Kitchener

  - Doon Creek
  - Victoria Common
- Stoney Creek

  - Orchard Park

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace the final echo, you need to close the ul and then the li

```
echo '</ul></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution to fix the error is obvious, it does not answer the question. We need to know what browser does when it has to parse invalid html code. It will not show us the error, but it will use some algorithm to overcome the error and insert correct element in dom tree. The name for this is `browsers error tolerance` and it differs slightly in between browsers. More than that, it may change with browser upgrade, so there is you answer: IE8 browser error tolerance is maybe not wrong, but is different compared to other browsers in case of ***li end-tag found with opening tag omitted***

Developers should read [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/).

Comment: The accepted answer _does_ answer the question of "why is IE 8 doing this?".  It is "doing this" because the code was wrong (mismatched tags).  Error tolerance, however, explains why other browsers or versions may _not_ be behaving this way.  More modern browsers may _tolerate_ such _errors_ by attempting to fix them.

Comment: Yes, but partially. He is specific with `this works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE 9 but not in IE 8.`. Why would same code work correctly in other browsers? Complete answer to that question cannot be simple `replace the final echo...`

Comment: Yes, but OP did not ask "Why would same code work correctly in other browsers?".  OP asked "why is IE 8 doing this?".

Comment: It depends on perception, I understood the question exactly like you quoted.

Answer (score -1):

Try to swap closing ul and li like this:

```
<ul>
                <?php

                        foreach ($pages['results'] as $row => $value) {
                                echo '<li>' . $row . '<ul>';
                                foreach ($value as $x => $y) {
                                        echo '<li><a href="#' . str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($y[2])) . '" title="' . $x . '">' . $x  . '</a></li>';
                                }
                                echo '</ul></li>'; //just swap closing elements
                        }

                ?>

            </ul>
```